# Windows Filter Driver and Filter Manager

Tags: windows, filter, driver

I am new to windows filter drivers. From the sample code of (MSDN) what I have seen is that, File system filter driver, has Filter Manager associated with it, and process filter driver doesn't have Filter Manager associated with it. So why is that difference?
So need some suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might want to read `Windows Internals` by Alex Ionescu, this will clear things up for you, starting from the bottom and will help you understand the whole thing.

Basically, in the past, filesystem filter drivers were built in a way that it would sit in a the right position in the exact filesystem DEVICE STACK, for example, NTFS. That way it would get the chance to filter IRPs.

Nowadays, the thing you mentioned, the filter manager (FLTMGR) has its own (legacy) driver at the top and on the bottom of the device stack, and it lets you register a callback function that everytime an IRP gets caughted, you'll get a chance to handle it.

Process (creation/deletion) filtering is a bit different, it is not handled using IRPs, basically in the call flow of NtCreateUserProcess on the kernel side there is a function responsible for calling whatever function registered for this kind of callback.

I hope that it clears things for you.

Comment: Thanks Herzel for your suggestion, it helped me a lot.